# About Pig job Jar fie

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm using embedded Pig to implement graph algorithm.
It works fine in local mode. But in a fully distributed Hadoop cluster,
there is always an error message like below: (Please see the last few lines)

```
2012-11-23 22:00:00,651 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - creating jar file Job4116346741117365374.jar
2012-11-23 22:00:09,418 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - jar file Job4116346741117365374.jar created
2012-11-23 22:00:09,423 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up multi store job
2012-11-23 22:00:09,431 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - BytesPerReducer=1000000000 maxReducers=999 totalInputFileSize=296
2012-11-23 22:00:09,431 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Neither PARALLEL nor default parallelism is set for this job. Setting number of reducers to 1
2012-11-23 22:00:09,442 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission.
2012-11-23 22:00:09,949 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job null has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2012-11-23 22:00:09,949 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2012-11-23 22:00:09,992 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 6015: During execution, encountered a Hadoop error.
2012-11-23 22:00:09,993 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2012-11-23 22:00:09,994 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics:

HadoopVersion    PigVersion    UserId    StartedAt    FinishedAt Features
0.20.1    0.10.0    jierus    2012-11-23 21:52:38    2012-11-23 22:00:09    HASH_JOIN,GROUP_BY,DISTINCT,FILTER,UNION

Some jobs have failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
Failed Jobs:
JobId    Alias    Feature    Message    Outputs
N/A    vec_comp,vec_comp_final,vec_comp_tmp HASH_JOIN,MULTI_QUERY    Message: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /tmp/Job4116346741117365374.jar does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1132)
```

Does anybody know which part of my code or operation is wrong?

Comment: Does /tmp has the right permission in the cluster nodes?

Answer (score 0):

It smells like you didn't specify the job tracker for pig (only specify the hdfs is not enough!). e.g.

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>10.xx.xx.99:9001</value>
</property>
```